# IIS Manager changes are saved to USER web.config instead APPLICATIONHOST.CONFIG

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8, iis-8.5, web.config

I face a problem when changing setting using IIS MANAGER in Windows 2012 R2. All changes made are stored in web.config user file, and this is a problem, beacuse when user update the App, the web.config is overwrighted and all changes are loose.

How can I change the IIS MANAGER to default edit APPLICATIONHOST.CONFIG and never update the user web.config at site level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open IIS on the server level and then click on the `Feature Delegation` in the `Management` section. Change all settings that you want to be stored in `ApplicationHost.config` to `Read only`

[image: Feature Delegation]

This is a server-wide setting for all sites, if you have existing sites that define some of these settings in their web.config , you may break them because their configuration becomes invalid.

Alternatively, you could use the `Configuration Editor` and never use the **normal icons**. In the configuration editor you can decide where to store the settings.